# SSIS Logging - Capture Variables?

Tags: sql-server, variables, logging, ssis, raiseevent

I'm trying to capture the values of about 15 variables within my sysssislog when my package executes.

I have set all the variables to true for "Raise event when variable value changes" and I understand I have to put some sort of object/code into the Event handler but I'm totally unsure as to what this should look like for the 15 variables.

Can anyone offer some examples please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the `RaiseChangedEvent` property is set to true on the variable the `OnVariableValueChanged` event will need be selected for logging to `SYSSSISLOG`.  This can be done by right-clicking the package and selecting **Logging** then going to the **Details** tab and checking the check-box for the `OnVariableValueChanged` event.  After this click the **Advanced** button and check the box for each element that will be logged, for instance `Computer`, `SourceName`, etc.  To see the actual value that the variable was changed to query the `SSISDB.CATALOG.EVENT_MESSAGES` DMV following package execution.  The `MESSAGE` column will show the value that the variable was set as during package execution.

Comment: Thanks for that, but this doesn't actually show the value of the variable that has changed. In the SYSSSISLOG table, it just shows the name of the variable that has changed.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you deploy the package to SSISDB and execute it from there, the SSISDB.CATALOG.EVENT_MESSAGES DMV will show the actual value that the variable is changed to.  When you execute the package, make sure the logging is at least at the Basic level.  Sorry, I thought you were aiming to use SYSSSISLOG, but the SSISDB DMVs will provide much more comprehensive details on package statistics.

Comment: Thanks mate, that's exactly right, the SSISDB DMVs are awesome.

Comment: No problem, my answer is updated with this info.  Glad it helped.